# How to retrieve client's IP and PORT on the server socket end?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a socket listener java based running on the desktop end and I have a mobile client, which is able to connect with this socket server without any issues. I want to have the socket connection established for each client separately, when client is trying to access new connection. I read from this link, [Reference link for multiple connection detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439472/how-the-clients-client-sockets-are-identified)

about how socket can differentiate for multiple connections. It is mentioned that based on the Client connection's IP and PORT detected on the socket server and the connection is made unique for each connection. Client PORT will differ for each connection. I read that, we can call `getpeername` to get the client connection's IP and PORT on the socket server end. But, i couldn't see any such API available in Java and then found the below one.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
System.out.println("server.getInetAddress();: " + server.getInetAddress());
```

But, It is returning always `server.getInetAddress():- 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0`
when the mobile client (Simulator) is calling this socket.

Could someone advise me, why I'm not getting the client's IP and PORT using the above InetAddress API on the socket end? Or Do I need to use different approach?

Answer (score 10):

When the server `accept`s a connection you get a `Socket` that represents that connection. `Socket` has a [`getInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29) method that will return the remote's address, and a corresponding [`getPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getPort%28%29) method that will return the remote's port.

For example:

```
Socket newSock = s.accept();
InetAddress addr = s.getInetAddress();
int         port = s.getPort();
```

Comment: However, it is important to note that the IP address you get may not be the IP address of the real client machine.  Consider the NAT case, and the HTTP proxy case.

Comment: Of course, it's the externally visible address to which you're connected, which may be a NAT gateway or a proxy.  Addresses behind those would not be routable anyway.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank you very much! I tried, "int port = server.getLocalPort()" instead of "s.getPort();". I'm trying from the same machine where I have mobile client simulator and socket also running, so it resulted "addr: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
port: 8080 "  like this...I think, I've have to test with the real physical mobile device, so that I'll get the actual client's IP and PORT properly, I guess.

Comment: It worked properly. It gives different client's IP address when I tried from different mobile device clients to access this socket. But, I'm always getting same client's PORT 8080 even-though I tried from different mobile clients like iOS, Android etc. Any idea what could be the reason? May be mobiles are connected in same wireless network?